# How to kill horses with pets around?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How do I kill horses that are near a swamp, when I have several pet dinosaurs around it? Can I set them on fire or kill them? The horses are too close to my pet dinosaurs to use `/butcher`. I tried using my dinosaurs to kill them but all of them go crazy.

Comment: Dinosaurs? Are you using mods?

Comment: I'm using dinosaur mod

Comment: How exactly all the mods used named, what are you exactly trying to do (and why), and **what have you tried so far**?

Comment: Also, Welcome to Arqade!

Answer (score 1):

Using commands (must be a server op or have cheats enabled), issue the following command to kill all horses within 30 meters:

`/kill @e[type=EntityHorse,r=30]`

(Change the "30" to any other number you like. Smaller numbers affect a smaller area; horses farther than this many blocks away will live to neigh another day.)

If you are not an op, and it is not your server, you will need to ask an op to do it for you. If it is your server, or it is a singleplayer world without cheats enabled, you can enable cheats by opening your world to LAN and turning on the Cheats option when doing so.